# Python (visual studio) break on error

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I have Visual Studio 2015 with Python Tools, and I'm trying to debug a python application, but it doesn't break on a certain error.

The error is an IndexError, which can be reproduced with this code:

```
matrix = [5, 6, 7]
print matrix[2]
print matrix[5000]
```

Running this will gives me a message in the console, but it won't automatically break.
[image: Console message]

On the other hand, if I have a NameError:

```
nonExistingFunction()
```

It does break, allowing me to easily see where it wrong...
[image: It can break the code apparently]

**Is this normal? And is there a way to make visual studio break when there's an error like that IndexError?**

Here is a screenshot of the options window (no idea if this actually applies to python) and the python tools > debugging

[image: My settings for debugging, if that helps]
[image: My settings for python tools > debugging]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation of PVTS in the category [exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/debugging).

> If an error occurs while your program is being debugged, and you don't
>   have an exception handler for it, the debugger will break and show you
>   the error.

[image]

A section later they say:

> **If you are being interrupted often by the debugger breaking on
>   exceptions, or if the debugger is not breaking on some exceptions that
>   you would like it to break on, you can modify the settings in the
>   Exceptions window. On the Debug menu, click Exceptions, and expand the
>   Python Exceptions entry. Here you can see all the exceptions that are
>   already know and can be configured.**

For Visual Studio 2017,

> The Debug > Windows > Exception Settings menu command brings up a window in which you can expand Python Exceptions:

[image]

Comment: I have never used that window before, and it was always there... I guess that's visual studio, so full of features that you'll never run out of new things to learn. Thanks. I'll accept your answer as soon as I can (apparently there's a time limit to how soon you accept answers).